# Dynamic Delay time in Delay block

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to change delay time in Anylogic through slider but I noticed that even the variable is changing but not the actual delay time.

triangular( 50, Avg_dispute_cycle, 150 );

This is the distribution I am using for delay time. Avg_dispute_cycle is a variable and linked to slider value. Though the variable is changing but seems distribution is not changing . please guide on this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show us how you linked them and how the slider actually changes the variable

Comment: Show your delay block as well. Your setup should work

Comment: Everything seems find  - except for the fact that you have 7 compilation errors... maybe try fixing those first.  Try duplicating your situation in a very simple model - your setup should work..